# Java: Curious ImmutableList add

Tags: java, collections, guava

I don't understand this method implementation. It's

```
public static <T> List<T> add(List<T> list, T element) {
    final int size = list.size();
    if (size == 0) {
        return ImmutableList.of(element);
    } else if (list instanceof ImmutableList) {
        if (size == 1) {
            final T val = list.get(0);
            list = Lists.newArrayList();
            list.add(val);
        } else {
            list = Lists.newArrayList(list);
        }
    }
    list.add(element);
    return list;
}
```

Why not a straightforward `list.add(element)`?

Comment: What class does this come from? I can tell it's Guava, but other than that...

Comment: Interesting. It's keeping a singleton list as an immutable list but converting it to a mutable list when adding more elements. But what's the goal?

Comment: Where is this method implementation? Is there any JavaDoc for it? (It seems odd that it returns an `ImmutableList` on one code path but an `ArrayList` on another. But then, it's an `add` operation, so...)

Comment: As the implementation already hints at, the list might be immutable, in which case trying to add to it will produce an exception. Branch which is entered if list size is `1` appears to be a case of so-called "premature optimization" (maybe not so premature, but still): if size is one, there's no need to create a list iterator, one can just use `get()`. As for return value, this method seems to be intended to be used instead of `list.add`, because for empty list it produces `ImmutableList`, and for non-empty list it produces mutable list, without stating its behavior clearly.

Comment: I find it weird that we are trying to answer this seemingly random code without enough specification.

Comment: There's yet another issue with this method (signature). It obliterates the return value of `java.util.List#add` method. The caller of the method wouldn't know for sure if the given element was added to the given list!

Comment: Where did you see this piece of code?

Comment: As best I can tell this does not come from Guava proper - presumably you found it in your own codebase? It certainly seems like a poor approach to me, but without more context (e.g. the javadocs and intended usages) it's hard to say.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade: `List.add` is guaranteed, by specification, to return `true`.

Comment: @ColinD if I am reading it correctly, `j.u.List#add` documents that the return value is _specified by_ `j.u.Collection#add` which says: `_true_ if this collection changed as a result of the call (false otherwise -- this addendum is mine)`. This is a common treatment across the JCF.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade: Calling `add` on a `List` _must_ add that item to the list, and thus return `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is implementing adding to the list that's given. If the input list is an `ImmutableList`, it first creates a mutable list (since otherwise it can't add to it) and copies the elements to it. If it's not, it just uses the existing list.

It's a bit odd that it returns an `ImmutableList` if the list passed in is empty, but a (mutable) `ArrayList` if it's given a non-empty `ImmutableList` to add to, but perhaps that makes sense in the broader context of where and how it's used. But that inconsistency is definitely something I'd query in a code review.

Answer (score 2):

### Addition for `ImmutableList`

> Why not a strightforward `list.add(element)`?

You can't call that method if the given list is **immutable**. Actually you can but usually such a method will then throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. The [documentation](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#add-int-E-) of Guavas `ImmutableList#add` says

> **Deprecated**. Unsupported operation.
> Guaranteed to throw an **exception** and leave the list **unmodified**.

However the goal of the method seems to be to also **support addition** for `ImmutableList` by creating a **mutable clone**. So a *straightforward* implementation would be:

```
public static <T> List<T> add(List<T> list, T element) {
    if (list instanceof ImmutableList) {
        // Create mutable clone, ArrayList is mutable
        list = Lists.newArrayList(list);
    }
    list.add(element);
    return list;
}
```

---

### Other stuff

Note that the type may change. While the input may be an `ImmutableList`, the output definitely **is not**.

You could keep the type by creating a temporary clone, adding to it (as shown) and then again wrap some `ImmutableList` around. However that doesn't seem to be a goal of this method.

Also note that the method in same cases may add something to the given list and in some create a new instance instead. So the caller of the method must be aware of the method sometimes changing his argument and sometimes not. For me this is a very odd behavior, it definitely must be highlighted in the documentation but I would not recommend doing stuff like that.

It seems that another goal of the method is to keep the list **immutable** if it was **empty** at method call. This is a bit strange but probably highlighted in its **documentation**. Therefore they add this call:

```
if (size == 0) {
    return ImmutableList.of(element);
}
```

Besides that they do some *minor stuff* by calling

```
Lists.newArrayList();
```

instead of

```
Lists.newArrayList(list);
```

if the `list` is currently of size `1`. However I'm not sure why they do this step. In my opinion they could just leave it the way it was.

---

So all in all I would probably implement such a method as

```
/**
 * Creates a new list with the contents of the given list
 * and the given element added to the end.
 *
 * <T> The type of the lists elements
 *
 * @params list The list to use elements of, the list will not be changed
 * @params element The element to add to the end of the resulting list
 *
 * @return A new list with the contents of the given list and
 *   the given element added to the end. If the given list was
 *   of type {@link ImmutableList} the resulting list will
 *   also be of type {@link ImmutableList}.
**/
public static <T> List<T> add(List<T> list, T element) {
    List<T> result;

    // Create a Stream of all elements for the result
    Stream<T> elements = Stream.concat(list.stream(), Stream.of(element));

    // If the list was immutable, make the result also immutable
    if (list instanceof ImmutableList) {
        result = ImmutableList.of(elements.toArray(T[]::new));
    } else {
        result = elements.collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    return result;
}
```

By that you won't ever change the argument `list` and you will also keep the list `ImmutableList` if it was. Using the `Stream#concat` method makes things a bit more efficient here (it is a lazy method), otherwise we would need to create temporary clones in between.

However we do not know which goals your method has, so probably in the **context** of your specific method what it does it **makes more sense**.

Comment: Oops, think you were referring to your simplified implementation. In which case, why not return a new `ImmutableList`? Seems the most sensible thing  to do.

Comment: @Michael I would do that too. But as long as we don't know which class OP is actually referring to, we can only guess the reason.

Comment: But you've *already* provided your own implementation that changes the behaviour. So if you're going to do that, why not make it the best it can be?

Answer (score 2):

This method is an anti-pattern, and should not be used. It munges mutable and immutable data structures, providing the worst of both implementations.

- If you're using an immutable data structure you should make that clear in your types - casting to `List` loses that important context. See the *"Interfaces" not implementations* section of [`ImmutableCollection`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.html).
- If you're using a mutable data you should avoid doing linear-time copies and instead take advantage of the data structure's mutability (carefully).

It generally does not make sense to use the two types interchangeably - if you want to add things to an existing collection use a mutable collection you own. If you intend for the collection to be immutable, don't try to add things to it. This method discards that intent and will lead to runtime errors and/or reduced performance.

Comment: "if you're using an immutable data structure, you should make that clear in your types", wouldn't it be great if JDK defined immutable collection types parallel to mutable ones, and extracted a common superinterfaces for those, so numerous libraries didn't follow this faulty approach of implementing immutable classes on top of mutable ones, that throw exceptions on attempt at modifying them.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov it certainly would be, but that ship has somewhat sailed (in Java, anyways) :) I've also spoken to JDK devs who've expressed concern that, in practice, the resulting type hierarchy would be very difficult to work with[citation needed]. Rust's approach, encoding mutability in the pointer's type, rather than as a fact of the underlying data structure, is quite interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this method is not "a straightforward `list.add(element)`" is because this method is designed to be able to add elements to `ImmutableList`s. Those are, quite obviously, immutable (if you look, their native `add` method [throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava-gwt/12.0/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.java#ImmutableCollection.add%28java.lang.Object%29)) and so the only way to "add" to them is to create a new list.

The fact that the newly returned list is now mutable is a strange design decision and only a wider context or input from the code's author would help solve that one.

The special case where an empty input list will return an immutable list is another strange design decision. The function would work fine without that conditional branch.

---

Because this method returns a copy of the list, you should be careful to assign the result to something, probably the original variable:

```
myList = TheClass.add(myList, newElement);
```

and note that the following usage will effectively do nothing:

```
TheClass.add(myList, newElement);
```